# How to insert data by using json in postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables called `book` and `author`.

```
create table book(bookid BIGSERIAL,
           bookname VARCHAR,
           book_type VARCHAR,
           book_pub_date DATE
           );

create table Author(Authorid BIGSERIAL,
           Authorname VARCHAR,
           Author_emailadddr VARCHAR,
           Author_phone integer
           );
```

Application will pass the data in JSON format thru  stored  function.
So how to store the JSON data into a tables?

Input data (Application will pass the following data thru stored function):

```
{
    "bookid" : "1",
    "bookname" : "sample book",
    "book type" : "history",
    "book_pub_date" : "2015-09-08",
    "Author" : [{
            "Authorname" : "xyz",
            "Author_emailadddr" : "xyz@gmail.com",
            "Author_phone" : "080-99978754"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to parse the  json data into a tables?

(I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need Postgres 9.3+ for a pure sql solution.  9.2 has limited json functionality compared to newer versions.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL 9.2 you will need to use a function written with pl/perl, pl/python, etc, using the relevant JSON decoding support for that language, and using the SPI to then insert the extracted data into tables. Use, e.g. Python's `json` module or Perl's `JSON` module to extract the fields, then the relevant SPI calls to create SQL to do the inserts based on the extracted data.

See:

- [Python `json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [perl `JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm)
- [pl/pythonu](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) or [pl/perlu](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html)

In particular, note the sections of the plperl and plpython docs for interacting with the database and running queries.

It's really not much different to doing it with an external script.

---

In PostgreSQL 9.4 and above you could start to use PostgreSQL's own [json support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to extract parts of the json in pl/pgsql and `insert` the extracted sections. No more need for plperl or plpython.