# To store json values in a variable

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres functionand input parameter is json. I need to extract values from this JSON and insert it in different tables.

Admin will be creating form,section,steps,question from front end and these data I will be getting as JSON and I need to insert the data into tables accordingly. Here each form can have n number of sections, ecah sections can have n number of steps,each steps have n number of questions like that. My idea is to extract the values from JSON into variables and use this variables to insert into tables. I am quite new to postgres, so don;t know whether this is a good idea.

Please find the JSOn I will be getting

```
{  
   "functionId":"",
   "subFunctionId":"",
   "groupId":"Audit",
   "formId":"",
   "formName":"sample form",
   "submittedBy":"2000269",
   "createdDate":"2015-08-06",
   "updatedBy":"",
   "updatedDate":"",
   "comments":"",
   "formStatusId":"",
   "formStatus":"",
   "formLanguage":"",
   "isFormConfigured":"",
   "formChange":"Yes",
   "sectionLevelChange":"Yes",
   "isActive":"",
   "formVersionNo":"",
   "formFooterDetails":"",
   "formHeaderDetails":"",
   "images":[  
      {  
         "imageId":"",
         "imageTempId":"",
         "imageTempUrl":"",
         "imageName":"",
         "imageUrl":"",
         "isDeleted":"",
         "imagesDesc":""
      }
   ],
   "imagesDescLevel":"",
   "sectionElements":[  
      {  
         "sectionElement":[  
            {  
               "sectionId":"",
               "sectionTempId":"sectionId+DDMMHHSSSS",
               "sectionName":"section1",
               "sectionChange":"Yes",
               "stepLevelChange":"Yes",
               "sectionLabel":"",
               "sectionOrder":"",
               "outOfScopeSection":"false",
               "punchListSection":"false",
               "images":[  
                  {  
                     "imageId":"",
                     "imageTempId":"",
                     "imageTempUrl":"",
                     "imageName":"",
                     "imageUrl":"",
                     "isDeleted":"",
                     "imagesDesc":""
                  }
               ],
               "imagesDescLevel":"",
               "isDeleted":"",
               "stepElements":[  
                  {  
                     "stepElement":[  
                        {  
                           "stepId":"",
                           "stepTempId":"stepId+DDMMHHSSSS",
                           "stepName":"step1",
                           "stepLabel":"",
                           "stepOrder":"",
                           "stepChange":"Yes",
                           "questionLevelChange":"Yes",
                           "images":[  
                              {  
                                 "imageId":"",
                                 "imageTempId":"",
                                 "imageTempUrl":"",
                                 "imageName":"",
                                 "imageUrl":"",
                                 "isDeleted":"",
                                 "imagesDesc":""
                              }
                           ],
                           "imagesDescLevel":"",
                           "isDeleted":"",
                           "questionAnswerElements":[  
                              {  
                                 "questionAnswerElement":[  
                                    {  
                                       "questionId":"",
                                       "questionClientUid":"",
                                       "questionDescription":"",
                                       "questionAccessibility":"",
                                       "isPunchListQuestion":"",
                                       "questionChange":"Yes",
                                       "questionOrder":"",
                                       "isDeleted":"",
                                       "images":[  
                                          {  
                                             "imageId":"",
                                             "imageTempId":"",
                                             "imageTempUrl":"",
                                             "imageName":"",
                                             "imageUrl":"",
                                             "isDeleted":"",
                                             "imagesDesc":""
                                          }
                                       ],
                                       "imagesDescLevel":"",
                                       "answerId":"",
                                       "answerClientUid":"",
                                       "elements":[  
                                          {  
                                             "element":[  
                                                {  
                                                   "elementId":"",
                                                   "elementMapId":"",
                                                   "clientUid":"",
                                                   "clientClass":"",
                                                   "imageTempId":"",
                                                   "imageTempUrl":"",
                                                   "elementType":"Question",
                                                   "elementOrder":"",
                                                   "elementArributuesProp":[  
                                                      {  
                                                         "attributeId":"",
                                                         "attributeName":"",
                                                         "defaultValue":""
                                                      }
                                                   ],
                                                   "elementArributuesVal":[  
                                                      {  
                                                         "value1":"item1"
                                                      }
                                                   ],
                                                   "rule":[  
                                                      {  
                                                         "ruleId":"1",
                                                         "ruleName":"Mandatory",
                                                         "formula":"i>a",
                                                         "formulaData":"i>50",
                                                         "isDeleted":"",
                                                         "addAction":[  
                                                            {  
                                                               "actionId":"1",
                                                               "actionDescription":"",
                                                               "actionTag":"",
                                                               "actionOutput":"",
                                                               "actionOutputValue":"",
                                                               "numberOfFields":"",
                                                               "isDeleted":""
                                                            }
                                                         ]
                                                      }
                                                   ]
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I extract values into variables from JSON. Any help is greately appeciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you already defined a schema (tables, relations, etc.) that will accomodate the data? You could write a function which takes one *object* a time (a certain form, section, step or question) and executes some dynamic sql to populate the right table, returning some reference/key. That function would be called all the times needed by another wrapper function which handles the whole json input. Here is a useful reference to start: [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: Or, you could even store the json *as is* in a `jsonb` field. That really depends on what you need to perform on the data, since the performance would drop drastically and query complexity would raise accordingly in this case. If you only whish to *store* the data, then a single `jsonb` filed is a good way to go.

Comment: Looks like a very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32458524/398670

Comment: You probably want to use pl/pgsql and PostgreSQL's json functions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), especially `json_each`

Comment: Hi Eggplant and Craig, I actually need to get the data and insert into around 20 base tables which have dependencies.I checked your link, but I am not getting any idea on how to get each value(not as pair) into a variable, so that I can write insert queries with this variable. I am sorry I am new to postgres(even to DB side).

Answer (score 0):

I could fetch the details with following query

```
select 
     line_item4->'questionDescription',line_item6->'elementMapId',line_item7->'attributeId',line_item8->'value1',line_item9->'ruleId',line_item10->'actionId'
     from tbl d,
     json_array_elements(d.j->'sectionElements') l,
     json_array_elements(l->'sectionElement') AS line_item,
     json_array_elements(line_item->'stepElements') AS line_item1,
     json_array_elements(line_item1->'stepElement') AS line_item2,
     json_array_elements(line_item2->'questionAnswerElements') AS line_item3,
     json_array_elements(line_item3->'questionAnswerElement') AS line_item4,
     json_array_elements(line_item4->'elements') AS line_item5,
     json_array_elements(line_item5->'element') AS line_item6,
     json_array_elements(line_item6->'elementArributuesProp') AS line_item7,
     json_array_elements(line_item6->'elementArributuesVal') AS line_item8,
     json_array_elements(line_item6->'rule') AS line_item9,
     json_array_elements(line_item9->'addAction') AS line_item10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postgres function to get the value but you should know that how can you use them - For example, below I have got the value from the context column based on the specific id of the table -

```
    select id,context,(SELECT *
FROM json_array_elements((tr.context#>'{path}')::json) as obj
WHERE  obj->>'type' = 'Hospital' )->>'displayName' as each_attribute from task_results tr where tr.id = '11e99de6-f2c6-66e8-b45f-1ff041905861'
```

context column has this data -

```
{
"use": "",
"path": [
    {
        "id": "11e837f8-42f2-1c62-8cb2-f703eb1e89ad",
        "type": "Root",
        "displayName": "Virtual Hospital"
    },
    {
        "id": "11e837fb-7c5e-57e2-91ac-ab2e1b35a7e9",
        "type": "Hospital",
        "displayName": "Test hospital"
    },
    {
        "id": "11e8d3c4-e68a-0868-b88f-07054484efea",
        "type": "Room",
        "displayName": "vivek's room"
    }
],
"compoundId": "05a34eccd38956e6b7dc1ba85e5c04c29ef3b9cd5f15a73e448222780d4671c86"
```

}

so from the above json I just need the hospital name which is stored in displayName and the "type" should be hospital only. 
with the help of the above.